# Defining the same class twice in Ruby

Tags: ruby

The following code works but I don't understand why. I have two files. The first is a class called `walmart.rb` located at `active_market/walmart.rb`. Here is the class definition:

```
module ActiveMarket
    class Walmart
        def test_one
            puts "test one"
        end
    end
end
```

For my `Walmart` class I have "API implementations" for Walmart APIs such as Order, Fulfillment, Report, etc. So I created a folder and another class for my first API implementation at `active_market/walmart/order.rb`.

Here is the `Order` class definition:

```
class ActiveMarket::Walmart
  def test_two
    puts "test two"
  end

  class Order < ActiveMarket::Walmart
    def test_all
      test_two
      test_one
    end
  end

end
```

I wanted to be able to call `ActiveMarket::Walmart.new` and also `ActiveMarket::Walmart::Order.new`. In order to do this, I had to define class `ActiveMarket::Walmart` a second time as you see above and place the `Order` class inside. This worked as expected but I don't understand why I am able to successfully call all three of these functions.

```
ActiveMarket::Walmart.new.test_one
ActiveMarket::Walmart.new.test_two
ActiveMarket::Walmart::Order.new.test_all
```

So, the question is why does this work? Why am I able to call both `test_one` and `test_two` functions in the same class that are both defined in two completely different files? I would have expected that one of the `ActiveMarket::Walmart` classes to be overridden completely. Are there any downsides to this or should I change my implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby allows to reopen existing classes and add additional methods to it or to override existing method.

In your example, there is actually just one `ActiveMarket::Walmart` class that defines two instance methods.

Try this:

```
walmart = ActiveMarket::Walmart.new
walmart.test_one
#=> test one
walmart.test_two
#> test two
```

Answer (score 1):

For the explanation let's assume the first code block loads first, then the second code block.

The first code block defines the `ActiveMarket::Walmart` class with the `test_one` method. The second code block re-opens the class and adds the `test_two` method to the class. This behaviour is documented in the Ruby [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Module+Definition).

Generally speaking it's best to do most of the method definitions of `ActiveMarket::Walmart` in the `active_market/walmart.rb` file. This way you know where to look when you're searching for a specific definition. If the method `test_one` of `ActiveMarket::Walmart` was defined in `foo/bar.rb` for example, it wouldn't be intuitive to find.

If you have good reason to define methods of `ActiveMarket::Walmart` in another file, feel free to do so. In the end it's still your project and you should decide what code belong together in the same file.